# minimize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'var_list' with NCF

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, minimize

I'm trying to run an NFC recommender system project with MLP, GMF and TensorFlow library, most of the code worked, but I have a problem with this part

```
    with tf.name_scope("optimzation"):
        self.optimzer = self.optim.minimize(self.loss)
```

the model :

```
class NCF(object):
def __init__(self, embed_size, user_size, item_size, lr,
             optim, initializer, loss_func, activation_func,
             regularizer_rate, iterator, topk, dropout, is_training):
    """
    Important Arguments.

    embed_size: The final embedding size for users and items.
    optim: The optimization method chosen in this model.
    initializer: The initialization method.
    loss_func: Loss function, we choose the cross entropy.
    regularizer_rate: L2 is chosen, this represents the L2 rate.
    iterator: Input dataset.
    topk: For evaluation, computing the topk items.
    """

    self.embed_size = embed_size
    self.user_size = user_size
    self.item_size = item_size
    self.lr = lr
    self.initializer = initializer
    self.loss_func = loss_func
    self.activation_func = activation_func
    self.regularizer_rate = regularizer_rate
    self.optim = optim
    self.topk = topk
    self.dropout = dropout
    self.is_training = is_training
    self.iterator = iterator


def get_data(self):
  
    sample = self.iterator.get_next()
    self.user = sample['user']
    self.item = sample['item']
    self.label = tf.cast(sample['label'],tf.float32)
    
   
    


def inference(self):
    """ Initialize important settings """
    
    #self.regularizer = tf.estimator.experimental.l2_regularizer(self.regularizer_rate)
    self.regularizer =regularizers.L2(self.regularizer_rate)

   


    if self.initializer == 'Normal':
        self.initializer = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01)
    elif self.initializer == 'Xavier_Normal':
        self.initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
    else:
        self.initializer = tf.compat.v1.glorot_uniform_initializer()

    if self.activation_func == 'ReLU':
        self.activation_func = tf.nn.relu
    elif self.activation_func == 'Leaky_ReLU':
        self.activation_func = tf.nn.leaky_relu
    elif self.activation_func == 'ELU':
        self.activation_func = tf.nn.elu

    if self.loss_func == 'cross_entropy':
        # self.loss_func = lambda labels, logits: -tf.reduce_sum(
        #       (labels * tf.log(logits) + (
        #       tf.ones_like(labels, dtype=tf.float32) - labels) *
        #       tf.log(tf.ones_like(logits, dtype=tf.float32) - logits)), 1)
        self.loss_func = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits

    if self.optim == 'SGD':
        self.optim = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.lr,
                                                       name='SGD')
    elif self.optim == 'RMSProp':
        self.optim = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(self.lr, decay=0.9,
                                               momentum=0.0, name='RMSProp')
    elif self.optim == 'Adam':
        self.optim = tf.optimizers.Adam(self.lr, name='Adam')


def create_model(self):
    with tf.name_scope('input'):
        self.user_onehot = tf.one_hot(self.user,self.user_size,name='user_onehot')
        self.item_onehot = tf.one_hot(self.item,self.item_size,name='item_onehot')

    with tf.name_scope('embed'):
        self.user_embed_GMF =tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(inputs = self.user_onehot,
                                              units = self.embed_size,
                                              activation = self.activation_func,
                                              kernel_initializer=self.initializer,
                                              kernel_regularizer=self.regularizer,
                                              name='user_embed_GMF')

        self.item_embed_GMF = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(inputs=self.item_onehot,
                                              units=self.embed_size,
                                              activation=self.activation_func,
                                              kernel_initializer=self.initializer,
                                              kernel_regularizer=self.regularizer,
                                              name='item_embed_GMF')

        self.user_embed_MLP = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(inputs=self.user_onehot,
                                              units=self.embed_size,
                                              activation=self.activation_func,
                                              kernel_initializer=self.initializer,
                                              kernel_regularizer=self.regularizer,
                                              name='user_embed_MLP')
        self.item_embed_MLP = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(inputs=self.item_onehot,
                                              units=self.embed_size,
                                              activation=self.activation_func,
                                              kernel_initializer=self.initializer,
                                              kernel_regularizer=self.regularizer,
                                              name='item_embed_MLP')



    with tf.name_scope("GMF"):
        self.GMF = tf.multiply(self.user_embed_GMF,self.item_embed_GMF,name='GMF')

    with tf.name_scope("MLP"):
        self.interaction = tf.concat([self.user_embed_MLP, self.item_embed_MLP],
                                     axis=-1, name='interaction')

        self.layer1_MLP = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(inputs=self.interaction,
                                          units=self.embed_size * 2,
                                          activation=self.activation_func,
                                          kernel_initializer=self.initializer,
                                          kernel_regularizer=self.regularizer,
                                          name='layer1_MLP')
        self.layer1_MLP = tf.compat.v1.layers.dropout(self.layer1_MLP, rate=self.dropout)

        self.layer2_MLP = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(inputs=self.layer1_MLP,
                                          units=self.embed_size,
                                          activation=self.activation_func,
                                          kernel_initializer=self.initializer,
                                          kernel_regularizer=self.regularizer,
                                          name='layer2_MLP')
            self.layer2_MLP = tf.compat.v1.layers.dropout(self.layer2_MLP, rate=self.dropout)

            self.layer3_MLP = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(inputs=self.layer2_MLP,
                                              units=self.embed_size // 2,
                                              activation=self.activation_func,
                                              kernel_initializer=self.initializer,
                                              kernel_regularizer=self.regularizer,
                                              name='layer3_MLP')
            self.layer3_MLP = tf.compat.v1.layers.dropout(self.layer3_MLP, rate=self.dropout)

    with tf.name_scope('concatenation'):
        self.concatenation = tf.concat([self.GMF,self.layer3_MLP],axis=-1,name='concatenation')


        self.logits = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(inputs= self.concatenation,
                                      units = 1,
                                      activation=None,
                                      kernel_initializer=self.initializer,
                                      kernel_regularizer=self.regularizer,
                                      name='predict')

        self.logits_dense = tf.reshape(self.logits,[-1])

    with tf.name_scope("loss"):

        self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(self.loss_func(labels=self.label, logits=self.logits_dense, name='loss'))
        # self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(self.loss_func(self.label, self.logits),
        #                               name='loss')

    with tf.name_scope("optimzation"):
        self.optimzer = self.optim.minimize(self.loss)


def eval(self):
    with tf.name_scope("evaluation"):
        self.item_replica = self.item
        _, self.indice = tf.nn.top_k(tf.sigmoid(self.logits_dense), self.topk)


def summary(self):
    """ Create summaries to write on tensorboard. """
    self.writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./graphs/NCF', tf.get_default_graph())
    with tf.name_scope("summaries"):
        tf.summary.scalar('loss', self.loss)
        tf.summary.histogram('histogram loss', self.loss)
        self.summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()




def build(self):
    self.get_data()
    self.inference()
    self.create_model()
    self.eval()
    self.summary()
    self.saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())

def step(self, session, step):
    """ Train the model step by step. """
    if self.is_training:
        loss, optim, summaries = session.run(
            [self.loss, self.optimzer, self.summary_op])
        self.writer.add_summary(summaries, global_step=step)
    else:
        indice, item = session.run([self.indice, self.item_replica])

        prediction = np.take(item, indice)

        return prediction, item
```

The error : `TypeError: minimize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'var_list'`

all the project in the [github](https://github.com/yongtenglei/recommend-system/tree/1d44133b0275a34d7f92ac2f72910b6b4da79743/algorithm/ncf)

Comment: The syntax used for `minimize()` in your code is not correct as this optimizer method needs at least 2 parameters to minimize `loss` by updating `var_list`. Please check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer#minimize) link for your reference.